Way to pass the Image from a Camera to Java as a BufferedImage on Raspberry Pi 5?
I'm trying to pass the output of an ArduCam Camera connected to a Raspberry Pi 5 running Debian Bookworm to a Java program as a BufferedImage.
I've gotten this to work on Mac Silicon using Sarxos Webcam Capture, but I'm running into issues in the transition to Raspberry Pi, either in my build of OpenCV/JavaCV/JavaCPP or in a mismatch of drivers.
Is there a quick and dirty I/O lib that Java can use to pull live video from a camera as BufferedImage? I'm struggling with finding a solution to this.
I was hoping that OpenCV/JavaCV would provide the functionality that I need, but its a fairly heavy library, and I need this to run offline on the Pi for an extended period of time (12+ hours a day for a month), and I fear that I'd hit performance issues with how much space OpenCV/JavaCV needs to store locally.
I'm open to changing libraries, or using a different model Camera (considering buying the official PiCam Module 3).
